# How to dynamically clone class methods but be able to tell them apart in Python

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to write a wrapper for an external module in python. The module provides a method to conjugate a verb that expects 2 arguments. I would like to wrap it into several methods and I was wondering if there was a way to do it programatically.

i.e. instead of:

```
class X:
  def a(self,arg):
    return module.do(arg,'a')
  def b(self,arg):
    return module.do(arg,'b')
  ...
  def z(self,arg):
    return module.do(arg,'z')
```

I was trying to do:

```
class X:
  def a(self,arg):
    return module.do(arg,__name__)
    return module.do(arg,__name__)
  def __init__(self):
    setattr(self,'b',self.a)
    ...
    setattr(self,'z',self.a)
x = X()
x.a(y)
x.b(y)
x.z(y)
```

The problem is that **name** returns the top level method, not the current.
I tried both:

```
from inspect import stack
stack()[0][3]
import sys
sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

But when I call b() or z() I get 'a'.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Why not just wrap "do" with a new function that takes a string argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply setting all the `b` to `z` attributes of your class to point to the `a` method. This means that whenever somebody accesses `instance.b`, it gives back the `a` method (which is why the `co_name` is always `a`).

You can accomplish what you want like this:

```
import string

class X(object):
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in string.lowercase and len(name) == 1:
      def call_into_module(arg):
        return module.do(arg, name)
      return call_into_module

    return super(X, self).__getattr__(name)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much. I had no idea I could overwrite getattr

Comment: @Cameron: Is `name in string.lowercase` meant to check if `name` is a single lower-case letter?  It doesn't.

Comment: @Sven: Better? Thanks for calling me out on that :-)

Comment: @Cameron: I'd use `name.islower() and len(name) == 1` or `name in list(string.lowercase)`.  The `a`, `b`, `c` naming of the methods in the original post is only for the sake of example anyway, so it doesn't really matter. SO is designed for nitpicking, so I couldn't resist. :)

Comment: @Cameron: you're doing `super` wrong. It should be `super(X, self)`. This is an important distinction, because the point of `super` is that you don't have to hardcode the superclasses into the code when you call their methods.

Comment: @katrielalex: Holy cows, I'm not thinking today. You're totally right

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
class X:
    pass
for name in "abcdefghij":
    setattr(X, name, lambda self, arg, _name=name: module.do(arg, _name))
```

It's enough to add the methods to the class once -- it's not necessary to do this for every instance in `__init__()`.

Maybe a better alternative is overwriting [`__getattr__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

```
class X:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def foo(arg):
            return module.do(arg, name)
        return foo
```

Comment: The second option is what I was looking for. Thanks.